# Git clone/push/pull hangs on compressing objects (on specific pc and network)

Tags: macos, git, ssh, git-clone

I have very weird issue and its more than 2 days I cannot find a solution:

git freezes/hangs after i clone/pull/push on compressing objects:

```
remote: Counting objects: 284, done.
remote: Compressing objects:  11% (26/233)
```

Conclusions I came up:

- This only happens on my home wifi and my MAC laptop
- Its not SSH: works fine on any other network/wifi
- Its not network: it works fine with other laptop on this network
- This only happens on BitBucket!! Github works fine
- Repository work fine everywhere else

Could there be some weird setting blocking bitbucket on this laptop & particularly this network?

Comment: Such issues are hard to tackle down. But I doubt this is a specific blocking rule you see. I suggest you start using a network sniffer and trace the communication. I know it is encrypted, but I would expect you see a general issue like a huge package drop or similar.

Comment: No matter big or small repositories its still the same. So its not about package size.

Comment: I never claimed that. So what did the network sniffing reveal?

Comment: sorry, misunderstood statement. Not entirely sure how to do network sniffing. Any pointers where i could read about it?

Comment: Take a look at the `tcpdump` or `wireshark` utilities.